# Add a new object to a JS array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I've got a question about putting object into jquery array ive got this code

```
var currency_values = [];

$("#bar_" + id).each(function () {
    currency_values.push({
        currency: $(".currency").attr('id'),
        symbol: $(".symbol").attr('id')
    });
});

alert(currency_values[1].currency + " : " + currency_values[1].symbol);
```

It could be an n element array depends on how many currency and symbols are paired in id bar.

But it looks like only 0 element is available and adding new object overwrite the last one. Im stuck.

Comment: That's not a "jQuery array". It's plain JavaScript. In any case, **ids must be unique**. If you have more than one, the selector targets only one of them.

Comment: I'm not seeing the reason for the `.each()`, since an element selected by id must return only one result, and you are not using any information relevant to `#bar_id` in the function... Just skip it entirely and proceed only with the `currency_values.push(...)`

Answer (score 2):

That's because ID's are unique, and `$("#bar_" + id)` only selects the first element with that ID, so looping doesn't really make sense. You should probably be using classes ?